# DevDemon Editor removes html <span> element

Tags: devdemon, html, editor

The Devdemon Editor works very well, it uses Redactor.

I can insert the `<span>` element inside the Devdemon Editor, but after saving the entry, the `<span>` element is removed (i guess other elements would be removed to).

Without problems, elements such `<a>, <div>`, are recognized and once the entry saved `<a>, <div>` are not removed.

I read the doc about Redactor.js, I didn't find a solution.

So, how to setup Devdemon Editor, to accept elements such as `<span>` or others?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You probably needs to move to wygwym.

Comment: Hi Mufi, yet I didn't find a solution, but studying the Redactor.js with calm code the problem will be solved. Editor linked to Channel Image, give a very powerful editor tool.